# How can I copy my SIM card's phone number to the clipboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, copy-paste

I use an iPhone 12 mini with iOS 15. I can view my SIM card's phone number on `Settings -> Phone -> My number`, as shown below. How can I copy that phone number to the clipboard? I unsuccessfully tried short touch and long touch.

[image]

Note that if I click (= short touch) on the number, the number appears in some editable box, but if I click in that box, the number disappears:

[image]

Comment: Screenshot and Live Text should make it work